# How can I pass a customized value to a spring aop advice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

If I take a service method named `public void delete(int id);` as the pointcut, I want to add an after-returning advice on it, but I don't know what kind of object was deleted(however, the servlet which called the service knows the type value), so I was wondering if I can pass a customized value to this after-returning advice when it is activated, like `'user'`. I've already checked the related document on Spring's website and I still know nothing. I'd appreciate your answer, THX.

Comment: You have a `void` method so nothing is going to be returned so an `AfterReturning` is a bit useless. What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

One solution but its required refactoring in Service method

1) Refactoring

```
public class DeleteRequest {
   String type;
   Long id;
}

public boolean delete(DeleteRequest request){ // impl}
```

2) Use Around Advice
  2.1) Before proceeding method execution, read passed parameter & get to be deleted object for "XYZ" requirement.
  2.2) Capture result of delete method execution
      IF its TRUE then DO your stuff

Note: I used this approach for deleted entity notification. So how we can get deleted entity information in after-advice, hence keep it entity information in before phase & use it in after-successful execution.